# Can’t fix jitter effect on a moving character with a smoke simulation [mantaflow, blender 2.82]

Tags: animation, physics

I have a moving character that is to be replaced with a “smokey” one. However, no matter what I do (I think I fiddled with almost every possible combination of parameters), I always run into a problem, be it either:

- The simulation is too varied between frames and looks psychodelic.
- Simulation has too much of a “ladder” effect (cranking up sampling substeps doesn’t help)
- Simulation is jittery and “noisy”

After hours and hours of fiddling with parameters, [**this**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IirWnmggvkc) (link to youtube) is the best result that I managed to achieve. And it is absolutely terrible and unusable. (don’t look at the compositing, it is just a render of the simulation)
These are the settings used for this simulation (the scene is in 30FPS, no wind force is used, blender 2.82):

[image: settings used for simulation]

So, how do I fix it? Obvious and most crucial problems are:

- It is jittery af.
- Trail of smoke that character leaves after them is too disjointed (especially noticable in the first second of the video).

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Managed to fix the jitter, but not the "laddery" trail.

Changes:

Set Heat to 0.2;
Disabled noise;
Set dissolve to 12 frames.

Then in post fixed the disjointed trail via the vector blur effect.